# Divide every value in one column by the largest value based on the values of another column (subject)

Tags: r

I have a data list with a `subject` column and a `size` column like the sample data below. For each subject, I need to divide every value in the `size` column by the largest value so that the range between size values will be 0 - 1.

Take the sample data below as example, I need to divide every size value for subject 1 by 9 and divide every size value for subject by 8.

As there are a lot of subjects in my real data, is there any approach that I can do this for each subject automatically?

```
sample <- structure(list(subject = c("subject1", "subject1", "subject1", 
                                     "subject1", "subject1", "subject2", "subject2", "subject2", "subject2", 
                                     "subject2"), size = c(9L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                   -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000259dd551ef0>)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data table makes operations easy to do "by group" using the `by` argument:

```
sample[, result := size / max(size, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(subject)]
sample
#      subject size    result
#  1: subject1    9 1.0000000
#  2: subject1    8 0.8888889
#  3: subject1    5 0.5555556
#  4: subject1    8 0.8888889
#  5: subject1    3 0.3333333
#  6: subject2    4 0.5000000
#  7: subject2    4 0.5000000
#  8: subject2    8 1.0000000
#  9: subject2    4 0.5000000
# 10: subject2    2 0.2500000
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr` is helpful here. You can use the `group_by` function to do the calculation for each subject.

```
library(dplyr)

sample %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(subject) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(results = size / max(size))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
# Groups:   subject [2]
   subject   size results
   <chr>    <int>   <dbl>
 1 subject1     9   1    
 2 subject1     8   0.889
 3 subject1     5   0.556
 4 subject1     8   0.889
 5 subject1     3   0.333
 6 subject2     4   0.5  
 7 subject2     4   0.5  
 8 subject2     8   1    
 9 subject2     4   0.5  
10 subject2     2   0.25
```

Or if you no longer need the size column, then you can use `dplyr::mutate(size = size / max(size))`

**Data**

```
sample <-
  structure(
    list(
      subject = c(
        "subject1",
        "subject1",
        "subject1",
        "subject1",
        "subject1",
        "subject2",
        "subject2",
        "subject2",
        "subject2",
        "subject2"
      ),
      size = c(9L, 8L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 2L)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-10L),
    class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
  )
```